Compute with the stretch and shrink components of a glue length
I want to add some shrinkability to an existing glue, that already has a stretch component, and that also may have a shrink component (although it is not the case for me currently).
For instance:
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{12pt plus 1pt}
\setlength{\mylength}{\glueexpr \the\mylength minus 0.1pt \relax} % speculative syntax
\the\mylength % should show “12pt plus 1pt minus 0.1pt”

It happens that, in this lucky case where there is no preexisting shrink component and I just want to add one, I can do just what I did above, relying on the syntactic order LENGTH plus STRETCH minus SHRINK. This would fail in general, if there was a shrink component that I wanted to modify in some way (either by scaling it, or by adding a constant value to it, or by entirely replacing it with another value). This also fails in the symmetrical situation, where I want to set a stretch component but there is a preexisting shrink component.
How to extract or modify the stretch and shrink components of a glue?
The only related solution I found is how to drop the stretch and shrink components, which does not help.
Use case: add some shrinkability to inter-line and inter-paragraph spacing (\baselineskip, \parskip), which helps avoiding many hideous “underfull \vboxes”, that is, pages that are too empty and where inter-paragraph spaces are stretched far beyond reasonable.

You want to sum two complete glue specifications:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}

\setlength{\mylength}{12pt plus 1pt}

\setlength{\mylength}{\glueexpr \mylength + 0pt minus 0.1pt \relax}

\the\mylength % should show “12pt plus 1pt minus 0.1pt”

\end{document}


You don't need \the inside \glueexpr.
A bit more complicated is to replace a glue stretch or shrink component.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getgluestretch}[1]{% #1 = glue parameter
  0pt plus 
  \expandafter\strip@pt\gluestretch#1
  \ifcase\gluestretchorder#1%
    pt\or fil\or fill\or filll
  \fi
  minus 0pt
}
\newcommand{\getglueshrink}[1]{% #1 = glue parameter
  0pt plus 0pt minus
  \expandafter\strip@pt\glueshrink#1\space
  \ifcase\gluestretchorder#1%
    pt\or fil\or fill\or filll
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}

\setlength{\mylength}{12pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}

\the\mylength

\setlength{\mylength}{%
  \glueexpr
    \mylength - \getglueshrink\mylength +  0pt minus 0.1pt
  \relax
}

\the\mylength

\setlength{\mylength}{%
  \glueexpr
    \mylength - \getgluestretch\mylength +  0pt plus 1fil
  \relax
}

\the\mylength

\setlength{\mylength}{%
  \glueexpr
    \mylength - \getgluestretch\mylength +  0pt plus 1pt
  \relax
}

\the\mylength

\end{document}

We need to replace pt that's added to the value by \gluestretch with the correct glue order.

Replacing both is easy: just multiply the glue parameter by 1, as in
\setlength{\mylength}{1\mylength plus 1fil minus 3pt}

because multiplication by a factor kills the stretch and shrink components.
